# How can I set a Lua script to run  after each LPUSH to a certain list?

Tags: lua, redis

I'm interested in using a lua script to post process elements being pushed to Redis list.
So what I want to know is if there is a way to tell Redis:
"Always run lua script X after a value is pushed into list Y"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Unless you make your own command (in lua), which will call LPUSH and perform your post-processing. You have to also make all developers use that command instead of original LPUSH (when corresponding keys are concerned). Good luck on that :)

Comment: Actually that's a great idea for my case. as this push would be performed by one app, not just anybody. And I can make the script to check for a previous illegal LPUSH at the end too.

Comment: Additionally, if you wanted to make sure nobody calls `LPUSH`, you could use `rename-command` to rename it to a secret.

Comment: @LinusGThiel, oh yeah, right. Thanks for reminding about this functionality :)

Comment: I still want that command to be available for other purposes, in other lists. But that's a great tip.